# Android: how to do this animation?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-animation

There is an ImageView with a drawable resource. The animation should begin empty, the resource should progressively appear from the top edge, then it should continue shifting towards the lower edge until it disappear again beyond that. 
I'd like to start this animation whenever I want and make it repeat endlessly until I decide to stop it. Any help?

Comment: Please add some code of what you have already tried!

Comment: if I had some experience I would have done, I asked for some hint or help, not a solution

Comment: for example, use this framework, read this guide, something that will point me in the right direction. What's the problem? We can't be all experts

Comment: I am sorry, but it can't be that hard to google "android animations", go to the first link (the official developers guide) and get started with the very basics. Then tinker around to try get the wanted result.
If you then have a problem -> go to StackOverflow;
Nobody starts as an "expert" but you have to do the first steps on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use one of this libraries, this libraries help you and have many examples

- https://github.com/2359media/EasyAndroidAnimations
- https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

Comment: THIS is a help, thank you. Now I can practice a lot more than I expected

Comment: Sometimes it is better to use a library to learn and watch cases. Then you can apply what you've learned

Answer (score 1):

Also animating resources is possible by writing custom view and modifying onDraw() function, it is not necessary in your case. You need a ViewGroup with an ImageView nested inside. You set your imageview top-padding -imageHeight which make it disappear at the beginning. than you can use property animator (or object animator) to increase top-padding over time up to 0 and dada! now you have your imageview fully shown on the screen.

property animation is an easy concept you can grasp in 5 minutes! Right now i don't have a IDE so there would be no code. good luck